# How long is this week's parasha as compared to others?

Tags: number, parsha-torah-portion, size, statistics

We read *parashas Ekev* today. My kid noted that it's listed as having 111 verses, and asked me whether that's a long *parasha*. I didn't know where it lies among the *parashiyos*, so I ask:
**Where do various lengths lie in the range of weekly-*parasha* lengths? What's a long one, a typical one, a short one?**

Comment: Eikev stats from [Torah Tidbits](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1793607/1054.txt) include: "231.83 lines in a Torah; rank: 14th. 111 p'sukim - ranks 26th (4th in D'varim). Same number as Vayikra, but larger. 1747 words - ranks 16th (3rd in D'varim). Same number as Ki Tavo; Ki Tavo has more p'sukim; Eikev has more letters. 6865 letters - rank: 14th (3rd in D'varim). Eikev's p'sukim are long - 3rd longest in the Torah in words and letters per pasuk. This accounts for rise in ranking in those categories."

Answer (score 3):

The table on page 86 (page 22 in the PDF) of Sheldon Epstein, Bernard Dickman, and Yonah Wilamowsky's paper ["Parsha Management — Doubling, Halving, Accuracy"](http://www.hakirah.org/vol%202%20epstein.pdf)<sup>[1]</sup> is of the *parashiyos* and their lengths. According to the data in that table, we have:

Counting each *parasha* separately, the deciles are 176 (100%), 148 (90%), 134 (80%), 122 (70%), 118 (60%), 110.5 (50%), 105 (40%), 96 (30%), 86 (20%), 65 (10%), and 30 (0%).

If we include doubled *parashiyos* in the count (and also their component *parashiyos*), we wind up with 244 (100%), 157 (90%), 146 (80%), 126 (70%), 122 (60%), 112 (50%), 106 (40%), 97 (30%), 87 (20%), 67 (10%), and 30 (0%).

Thus, a *parasha* 111 *p'sukim* long is longer than half the *parashiyos* and shorter than the other half.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I have not read and cannot vouch for this paper. But I see no reason to doubt the data in the table I'm citing.